# Ionic 4 app not working in android device

Tags: cordova, ionic4

i made simple ionic 4 app with {ionic start myApp tabs},when run on browser its work . but when build APK and install on android Os not work and display white screen!

Comment: What version of Android are you deploying to? I recently had this issue with a newly started Ionic 4 app; the version of Android I was deploying to was too old

Answer (score 0):

Go to AVD manager in Android Studio, select your device to emulate and choose *Cold Boot now*.
One this done, run `ionic cordova run android` and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

When I had this issue, I saw that I was getting errors in Android Studio: `Failed to construct 'HTMLElement': Please use the 'new' operator.`

I fixed it with the answer from [this](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/24556) page:

Add this to your polyfills.ts on the bottom of your file

```
/***************************************************************************************************
 * APPLICATION IMPORTS
 */
import '@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/custom-elements-es5-adapter.js';
```

make sure to have the module installed with `npm install @webcomponents/webcomponentsjs --save-dev`