# How can I run ionic-angular application that calls APIs as Android App on a device

Tags: android, angular, ionic4

I have built an ionic angular application that connects to an API end point. On the web browser it works well. I compiled it for Android platform and opened it on the Android studio. When I connect my phone to the PC and run the application, it opens the login page which by default loads when the application starts up. However, immediately upon starting up it is supposed to make an API call which loads the initialization data, it instead generates a message as shown in the image attached.
[error from API call in ionic-angular app on android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SkroE.png)
I have tried to find out, but it seems that the API calls are being blocked as the initialization data is not retrieved from the remote server. I checked through and found some related problems but their solutions never worked for me. Some of the links I referred to are:
[XMLHttpRequest failed on App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30360244/xmlhttprequest-failed-on-app)
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-whitelist/
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54275697/ionic-4-app-not-working-in-android-device#:~:text=2%20Answers&text=Go%20to%20AVD%20manager%20in,android%20and%20it%20should%20work.&text=When%20I%20had%20this%20issue,use%20the%20'new'%20operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54275697/ionic-4-app-not-working-in-android-device#:%7E:text=2%20Answers&text=Go%20to%20AVD%20manager%20in,android%20and%20it%20should%20work.&text=When%20I%20had%20this%20issue,use%20the%20%27new%27%20operator).

Could someone point me to some info that can help me fix this issue.

I am relatively new in Angular and Ionic programming and I don't have a experience in using raw JavaScript though I use TypeScript in Angular framework.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix my issue with the help from the link

https://imstudio.medium.com/android-8-cleartext-http-traffic-not-permitted-73c1c9e3b803